# How to write a SQL query in Pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, azure-databricks

I have a SQL query that I am trying to convert into pyspark
the query looks like this

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_TABLE SET A_CONVERSION_TEMPLATE.[STATUS] = "OTHER/MENTIONED" WHERE (((EMPLOYEE_TABLE.[HOLIDAY_TAKEN]) Is Null));
```

Second Query:

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_TABLE SET EMPLOYEE_TABLE.[STATUS] = "OTHER/MENTIONED" WHERE (((EMPLOYEE_TABLE.STATUS) Is Null));
```

Third Query with two conditions

```
UPDATE EMPLOYEE_TABLE SET EMPLOYEE_TABLE.[LANGUAGE] = "ENGLISH", 
WHERE (((EMPLOYEE_TABLE.LANGUAGE[])<>"ENGLISH") AND ((EMPLOYEE_TABLE.FLAGYESNO)="Y"));
```

The Pyspark queries I am trying are
I have combined the first and second queries because in both we have to update the same column. The query I am using is

```
df=df.withColumn('STATUS', F.when( (col('STATUS')==''),'OTHER/MENTIONED').
otherwise(when(   (col('HOLIDAY_TAKEN]')==''), 'OTHER/MENTIONED').
otherwise('NULL')))
```

> When I am running my df it is updating everything to null in my
> 'STATUS' Column even the values which were already present it is
> changing it to 'NULL'

For the third query, I am getting no idea.
Please let me know if need other information.
Attaching the Output for more understanding
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vk79B.png)
**Thanks in advance for your responses**

Comment: Could you please add your sample schema and expected output for better understanding?

Comment: Attached a SS for your reference. we have to satisfy the conditions according to the sequence of queries i have shared.

Comment: There are two problems in your Pyspark code: first one is the part `otherwise('NULL')`. You need `otherwise(col('STATUS'))`. And the second problem is that you compare to `''` (empty string). You should check for [isNull](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.0/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.isNull.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a data frame as follows:

   ```
            +----------+----------+-------------+
            |DEPARTMENT|    STATUS|HOLIDAY_TAKEN|
            +----------+----------+-------------+
            |        HR|      null|        TAKEN|
            |   MANAGER|      null|        TAKEN|
            |        HR|   WORKING|      ONLEAVE|
            |  ENGINEER|ONCONTRACT|    SICKLEAVE|
            |        PA|      null|         null|
            |       CEO|   ON VISA|         null|
            |  ENGINEER|      null|         null|
            |   MANAGER|      null|         null|
            +----------+----------+-------------+
   ```
2. Then write a condition satisfying both the conditions in a single query:

   ```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as fx
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *

    expression = """CASE 
                        WHEN (HOLIDAY_TAKEN IS NULL AND STATUS IS NULL) OR (HOLIDAY_TAKEN IS NOT NULL AND STATUS IS NULL) THEN 'OTHER/MENTIONED' 
                        ELSE STATUS 
                    END"""

    df2 = df.withColumn('STATUS',fx.expr(expression))

    df2.show()
   ```

Please check the below image for your reference:
[image]